# vb.net 2022 alterate events after a Designer modify

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms, events, visual-studio-2022

I'm a newer in vb.net and with vb.net 2022 (project: Windows Form App) when I change something in a form Design sometimes all object's event are recreated and the old are not more linked to object.

For example I add a label or modify a button and all form's events are recreated.
I've to relink it but it's a solution.
Do you know where I wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen a couple of people report this same issue and one of them said that it is apparently a bug in VS that should be fixed in the next version (17.5.2). You can roll back to the last 17.4.x version if it's a major problem for you.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried the same code with Visual Studio 2019 and it's ok !  And it's faster

Comment: Yeah, but you can't target a version of .NET that will still be supported in a year's time.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Form-Events-lost-on-compile-and-run-afte/10283572

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.